# Rolling several dice (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to understand how to roll several dice at the same time, but with for each one a different random value.

The thing is, I need to ask how many dice the player wants to roll, and I don't understand how to do it, so that's why I'm looking for help here.

One last thing, the dice is a sprite of 100pixels width and 100pixels height.

```js
// the dice div
function createDice() {
    let divDice = document.createElement('div');
    divDice.className = 'dice';
    document.querySelector('#player').appendChild(divDice);
    }

// multiple dice throw
let enteredNumber = Number(prompt("How many dice do you want to roll?"));
for (let i=0; i<enteredNumber; i++) {
    createDice();
};

// function rollDice
function rollDice(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
let face = {
    min : 1,
    max : 6,
}

// function to print the right face of the dice
function diceImage (x) {
    document.querySelector('.dice').style.backgroundPosition = x;
}

// function to print the right face of the dice according to the random number
let dice = rollDice(face.min, face.max);
        console.log(dice);

if (dice === 1) {
        diceImage("600px 0");
    } else if (dice === 2) {
        diceImage("500px 0");
    } else if (dice === 3) {
        diceImage("400px 0");
    } else if (dice === 4) {
        diceImage("300px 0");
    } else if (dice === 5) {
        diceImage("200px 0");
    } else if (dice === 6) {
        diceImage("100px 0");
    };
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
}

#player {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

#dealer {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.board {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.dice {
  background-image: url('../images/dice-sprite.png');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
    <div id="app">
        <div class="board" id="player"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So what exact problem you face? If it rolls one dice, move code to functions and call it as much times as you want

Comment: The problem is that I managed to do it for one dice, but I really don't understand how to apply to N number of dices, if the player choose for exemple 5 dices, the first one only will have the random number and the good face associated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the minimal working example where you can start:

```js
function createDice() {
    let divDice = document.createElement('div');
    divDice.className = 'dice';
    divDice.innerHTML = rollDice()
    document.querySelector('#player').appendChild(divDice);
}

function rollDice() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 6 + 1)
}

function setupBoard() {
    let enteredNumber = Number(prompt("How many dice do you want to roll?"));
    for (let i=0; i<enteredNumber; i++) {
        createDice()
    };
}

setupBoard()
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
}

#player {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

#dealer {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.board {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.dice {
  background-image: 'green';
  color: black;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div class="board" id="player"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already got your answer, here is a little "advanced" version with animation:

```js
"use strict";
const input = document.getElementById("diceNum");
const player = document.querySelector('#player');
let face = {
    min : 1,
    max : 6,
}

// the dice div
function createDice(num) {
  const dice = document.querySelector("#diceTempl > .dice").cloneNode(true);
  
  dice.value = num;
  dice.setAttribute("num", rollDice(face.min, face.max, [num]));
  setTimeout(() => dice.setAttribute("num", num), 0);
  document.querySelector('#player').appendChild(dice);
  return dice;
}

function update(enteredNumber)
{

if (enteredNumber === undefined)
    enteredNumber = input.value;

  input.value = enteredNumber;
  if (player.children.length > enteredNumber)
  {
    while(player.children.length > enteredNumber)
      player.removeChild(player.lastChild);

  }
  const dices = []
  for (let i = 0, oldDice, dice, skip; i < enteredNumber; i++)
  {
    dice = (oldDice = player.children[i]) || createDice(rollDice(face.min, face.max));
    skip = [~~dice.getAttribute("num")]; //set to undefined to allow repeat number on the same dice
    if (oldDice)
      dice.setAttribute("num", dice.value = rollDice(face.min, face.max, skip));

    dices[dices.length] = dice;
  };
  console.clear();
  console.log("numbers:", dices.map(d => d.value).toString());
}
update(rollDice(1, 5));

// function rollDice
function rollDice(min, max, skip) {
  let n;
  do
    n = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  while(skip !== undefined && skip.indexOf(n) != -1);
  return n;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
}

#player {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

#dealer {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.board {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.dice
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  perspective: 300px;
  margin: 1em;
  --bgColor: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); /* background color during animation */
  --bgColorFront: rgba(255,255,255,0.95); /* background color of the visible face */
}

.dice > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-50px);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.dice > div > div
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background-color: var(--bgColor);
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukfHJ.png');
  transition: background-color 1s;

}

.dice[num="1"] > div
{
  transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateY(   0deg);
}
.dice[num="2"] > div
{
  transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateX(  90deg);
}
.dice[num="3"] > div
{
  transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateY( -90deg);
}
.dice[num="4"] > div
{
  transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateY(  90deg);
}
.dice[num="5"] > div
{
  transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateX( -90deg);
}
.dice[num="6"] > div
{
  transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.dice[num="1"] .num1
{
  background-color: var(--bgColorFront);
}
.dice[num="2"] .num2
{
  background-color: var(--bgColorFront);
}
.dice[num="3"] .num3
{
  background-color: var(--bgColorFront);
}
.dice[num="4"] .num4
{
  background-color: var(--bgColorFront);
}
.dice[num="5"] .num5
{
  background-color: var(--bgColorFront);
}
.dice[num="6"] .num6
{
  background-color: var(--bgColorFront);
}
.num1
{
  transform: rotateY(  0deg) translateZ(50px);
  background-position: 600px 0;
}
.num2
{
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
  background-position: 500px 0;
}
.num3
{
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(50px);
  background-position: 400px 0;
}
.num4
{
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
  background-position: 300px 0;
}
.num5
{
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(50px);
  background-position: 200px 0;
}
.num6
{
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(50px);
  background-position: 100px 0;
}

#diceTempl
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="diceTempl">
  <div class="dice">
    <div>
      <div class="num1"></div>
      <div class="num2"></div>
      <div class="num3"></div>
      <div class="num4"></div>
      <div class="num5"></div>
      <div class="num6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
number of dices: <input id="diceNum" type="number" min="1" max="30">
<button onclick="update()">Roll</button>
<div id="app">
  <div class="board" id="player"></div>
</div>
```